# How to loop through select options?

Tags: 2013

I have an app connected to a list. I have a select option in my app where I can choose between 5 sec,10 sec and 15 sec and that is a setting when the list should update.If I choose 5 sec the list should update every 5 sec etc. I am not shore how to loop through select options and there must be something wrong in my code . here's my code:

```
function chooseOpt() {
var lstString="";
var Enum = opt.getEnumerator();
while (Enum.moveNext()) {
    var currentItem = Enum.get_current();
    if (currentItem.get_item("5sec").selected) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you are just reading the value of the choice field, use get_item('ChoiceFieldName'). Pass this value to a switch construct which will have options 5, 10 and 15 and you can build logic for each option.

Comment: Is there any problem you are facing with this? I see you un-accepted the solution!